# Asp.net mvc 4 Ajax to call controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax call to the controller works for some pages like `http://localhost:2493/anything`, and does not work for `http://localhost:2493/Account/Login`.

this code work for the index page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
          url: 'Home/GetLinks',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
        $('#ListLinks').append('<li><a href="http://'+ val.Url +'" target="_new">' + val.Url + '</a></li>');
    });
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.log('Response code:' + xhr.status);
        console.log('[Error:' + err + '] ' + status);
    }
     });
});
```

When debug this code on pages like `http://localhost:2493/Account/Login` I got a error 404.

The JS code is placed in separeted file and its called on the _layout page.

I know the problem is url, so I tried to change the code and use

```
url: '@Url.Action("Home","GetLinks")',
```

Then it doesn't work on any page.

How can I write this bit code to work on any page.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a leading slash to the URL parameter of the ajax call.

This means get the URL from the root of the domain:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/Home/GetLinks',
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html helper `Url.Action` method won't work in your external js file. So create js variable( in global scope) in your razor view/Layout file and  use that in your external javascript file.

In your razor file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var global_GetLinks_Url="@Url.Action("GetLinks","Home")";
</script>
```

now you can access the `global_GetLinks_Url` in your external js files

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
          url: global_GetLinks_Url,
          //rest of your code goes here
});
```